# Taking a string and returning it with vowels removed

Tags: ruby, string

I'm attempting to write a function that takes a string and returns it with all vowels removed. Below is my code.

```
def vowel(str)
  result = ""
  new = str.split(" ")
  i = 0
  while i < new.length
    if new[i] == "a"
      i = i + 1
    elsif new[i] != "a"
      result = new[i] + result
    end
    i = i + 1
  end
  return result
end
```

When I run the code, it returns the exact string that I entered for (`str`). For example, if I enter `"apple"`, it returns `"apple"`.

This was my original code. It had the same result.

```
def vowel(str)
  result = ""
  new = str.split(" ")
  i = 0
  while i < new.length
    if new[i] != "a"
      result = new[i] + result
    end
    i = i + 1
  end
  return result
end
```

I need to know what I am doing wrong using this methodology. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you check for other vowels?

Comment: I noticed you haven't selected an answer. Were none helpful to you, not even Stefan's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Finding the bug

Let's see what's wrong with your original code by executing your method's code in [IRB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> str = "apple"
#=> "apple"
irb(main):002:0> new = str.split(" ")
#=> ["apple"]
```

Bingo! `["apple"]` is not the expected result. What does the [documentation for `String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-split) say?

> #### split(pattern=$;, [limit]) → anArray
>
> Divides *str* into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these substrings.
>
> If *pattern* is a `String`, then its contents are used as the delimiter when splitting *str*. If *pattern* is a single space, *str* is split on whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored.

Our pattern *is* a single space, so `split` returns an array of *words*. This is definitely not what we want. To get the desired result, i.e. an array of *characters*, we could pass an empty string as the pattern:

```
irb(main):003:0> new = str.split("")
#=> ["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"]
```

"split on empty string" feels a bit hacky and indeed there's another method that does exactly what we want: [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-chars)

> #### chars → an_array
>
> Returns an array of characters in *str*. This is a shorthand for `str.each_char.to_a`.

Let's give it a try:

```
irb(main):004:0> new = str.chars
#=> ["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"]
```

Perfect, just as advertised.

#### Another bug

With the new method in place, your code still doesn't return the expected result (I'm going to omit the IRB prompt from now on):

```
vowel("apple") #=> "elpp"
```

This is because

```
result = new[i] + result
```

*prepends* the character to the `result` string. To *append* it, we have to write

```
result = result + new[i]
```

Or even better, use the append method [`String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C):

```
result << new[i]
```

Let's try it:

```
def vowel(str)
  result = ""
  new = str.chars
  i = 0
  while i < new.length
    if new[i] != "a"
      result << new[i]
    end
    i = i + 1
  end
  return result
end

vowel("apple") #=> "pple"
```

That looks good, `"a"` has been removed (`"e"` is still there, because you only check for `"a"`).

---

Now for some refactoring.

#### Removing the explicit loop counter

Instead of a `while` loop with an explicit loop counter, it's more idiomatic to use something like [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Integer.html#method-i-times):

```
new.length.times do |i|
  # ...
end
```

or [`Range#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Range.html#method-i-each):

```
(0...new.length).each do |i|
  # ...
end
```

or [`Array#each_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-each_index):

```
new.each_index do |i|
  # ...
end
```

Let's apply the latter:

```
def vowel(str)
  result = ""
  new = str.chars
  new.each_index do |i|
    if new[i] != "a"
      result << new[i]
    end
  end
  return result
end
```

Much better. We don't have to worry about initializing the loop counter (`i = 0`) or incrementing it (`i = i + 1`) any more.

#### Avoiding character indices

Instead of iterating over the character indices via `each_index`:

```
new.each_index do |i|
  if new[i] != "a"
    result << new[i]
  end
end
```

we can iterate over the characters themselves using [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
new.each do |char|
  if char != "a"
    result << char
  end
end
```

#### Removing the character array

We don't even have to create the `new` character array. Remember the documentation for `chars`?

> This is a shorthand for `str.each_char.to_a`.

[`String#each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-each_char) passes each character to the given block:

```
def vowel(str)
  result = ""
  str.each_char do |char|
    if char != "a"
      result << char
    end
  end
  return result
end
```

The `return` keyword is optional. We could just write `result` instead of `return result`, because a method's [return value](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values) is the last expression that was evaluated.

#### Removing the explicit string

Ruby even allows you to pass an object into the loop using [`Enumerator#with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object), thus eliminating the explicit `result` string:

```
def vowel(str)
  str.each_char.with_object("") do |char, result|
    if char != "a"
      result << char
    end
  end
end
```

`with_object` passes `""` into the block as `result` and returns it (after the characters have been appended within the block). It is also the last expression in the method, i.e. its return value.

You could also use [`if` as a modifier](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless), i.e.:

```
result << char if char != "a"
```

---

#### Alternatives

There are many different ways to remove characters from a string.

Another approach is to filter out the vowel characters using [`Enumerable#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) (it returns a new array containing the remaining characters) and then [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-join) the characters (see [Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366855/477037) for a version to remove all vowels):

```
def vowel(str)
  str.each_char.reject { |char| char == "a" }.join
end
```

For basic operations like string manipulation however, Ruby usually already provides a method. Check out the other answers for built-in alternatives:

- `str.delete('aeiouAEIOU')` as shown in [Gagan Gami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32367314/477037)
- `str.tr('aeiouAEIOU', '')` as shown in [Cary Swoveland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366967/477037)
- `str.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '')` as shown in [Avinash Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366817/477037)

#### Naming things

[Cary Swoveland pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366803/taking-a-string-and-returning-it-with-vowels-removed/32372149?noredirect=1#comment52645461_32372149) that `vowel` is not the best name for your method. Choose the names for your methods, variables and classes carefully. It's desirable to have a short and succinct method name, but it should also communicate its intent.

`vowel(str)` obviously has something to do with vowels, but it's not clear what it is. Does it return a vowel or all vowels from `str`? Does it check whether `str` is a vowel or contains a vowel?

`remove_vowels` or `delete_vowels` would probably be a better choice.

Same for variables: `new` is an array of characters. Why not call it `characters` (or `chars` if space is an issue)?

**Bottom line:** read the fine manual and get to know your tools. Most of the time, an IRB session is all you need to debug your code.

Comment: @Stefen : very well explained. 1+ :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide such a detailed explanation! As an amateur programmer, this is exactly the type of break down I need in order to really understand what is happening.

Comment: This is an excellent way to teach a programming language. I don't think you're quite finished, however. After ending up with the method `vowel` (which is not the best name for what it's doing), shouldn't you step back and ask if it's necessary to inspect each character in the string?

Answer (score 6):

I should use regex.

```
str.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, "")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
> string= "This Is my sAmple tExt to removE vowels"
#=> "This Is my sAmple tExt to removE vowels" 
> string.delete 'aeiouAEIOU'
#=> "Ths s my smpl txt t rmv vwls"
```

You can create a method like this:

```
def remove_vowel(str)
  result = str.delete 'aeiouAEIOU'
  return result
end

remove_vowel("Hello World, This is my sample text")
# output : "Hll Wrld, Ths s my smpl txt"
```

### [Live Demo](http://repl.it/BFSD)

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Thank you mate :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're trying to learn about the basics of programming, rather than finding the quickest one-liner to do this (which would be to use a regular expression as Avinash has said), you have a number of problems with your code you need to change.

```
new = str.split(" ")
```

This line is likely the culprit, because it splits the string based on spaces. So your input string would have to be "a p p l e" to have the effect you're looking for.

```
new = str.split("")
```

You should also remove the duplicate `i = i+1` once you've changed that.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already identified the problems with the OP's code, I will merely suggest an alternative; namely, you could use [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
"Now is the time for all good people...".tr('aeiouAEIOU', '')
  #=> "Nw s th tm fr ll gd ppl..."
```

Answer (score 2):

If regex is not allowed, you can do it this way:

```
def remove_vowels(string)
  string.split("").delete_if { |letter| %w[a e i o u].include? letter }.join
end
```